# Strange Icon In Word 2016

Tags: microsoft-word

In the very latest version of Word I noticed a new icon next to a paragraph style I applied and accidentally clicked on it with my mouse. From that point onwards all text was deleted. Clicking on the symbol again and the text came back. I do not like this at all but do not know what it is called or if it can be turned off. If you are wondering I was an IT trainer for some 30 years specializing in Word Processing and I have never seen this before. Can anybody advise please? Many thanks in anticipation.

Answer (score 0):

I have found what the "problem" is. When I click on this icon and it is on a heading  1 style it collapses the document down to just that style heading. Click on a paragraph heading 2 style and it collapses just that paragraph. What caught me out was the whole document collapsing (as nearly did I) when I clicked on the Main Heading i.e. a level one style. Basically, I suppose, this a form of outlining but it did nearly outline me.

I also discovered that by clicking the icon again it restored the text. I wonder how may others have seen this? All this in Office 365 so I don't know about Office 2019.

Answer (score -1):

I assume you tried hovering the mouse over the icon, to try and get the name?

I couldn't find anything like you described but I am running the latest version of office 365. btw latest version of office is 2019 so is it that or 2016 you have this issue in?  Maybe you can screen shot the icon?

Comment: This is not an answer, it is a comment. Please delete this as an answer and repost as a comment.